# Unable to install django Mac terminal

Tags: python, django

I'm new to programming. Stating with python and django framework. When i try to install django via terminal following happens. Also, pls explain what is `sudo` and `--user`.

```
Last login: Sun Aug  2 20:43:02 on ttys000
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
Aruns-MacBook-Pro:~ arununnikrishnan$ mkdir vidly
mkdir: vidly: File exists
Aruns-MacBook-Pro:~ arununnikrishnan$ cd vidly
Aruns-MacBook-Pro:vidly arununnikrishnan$ pipenv install django==3.0.8
-bash: pipenv: command not found
Aruns-MacBook-Pro:vidly arununnikrishnan$ sudo pipenv install django==3.0.8
Password:
sudo: pipenv: command not found
Aruns-MacBook-Pro:vidly arununnikrishnan$ --user pipenv install django==3.0.8
-bash: --user: command not found
Aruns-MacBook-Pro:vidly arununnikrishnan$ sudo pip install pipenv
sudo: pip: command not found
Aruns-MacBook-Pro:vidly arununnikrishnan$ sudo easy_install pip
Searching for pip
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/pip/
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/36/74/38c2410d688ac7b48afa07d413674afc1f903c1c1f854de51dc8eb2367a5/pip-20.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=d75f1fc98262dabf74656245c509213a5d0f52137e40e8f8ed5cc256ddd02923
Best match: pip 20.2
Processing pip-20.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing pip-20.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Adding pip 20.2 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip3.8 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip3 script to /usr/local/bin

Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-20.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
Aruns-MacBook-Pro:vidly arununnikrishnan$ sudo pipenv install django==3.0.8
sudo: pipenv: command not found
Aruns-MacBook-Pro:vidly arununnikrishnan$ pip -V
pip 20.2 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-20.2-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7)
Aruns-MacBook-Pro:vidly arununnikrishnan$ pipenv install django==3.0.8
-bash: pipenv: command not found
Aruns-MacBook-Pro:vidly arununnikrishnan$ python3 -m venv ./venv
Aruns-MacBook-Pro:vidly arununnikrishnan$ source ./venv/bin/activate
(venv) Aruns-MacBook-Pro:vidly arununnikrishnan$ pipenv install django==3.0.8
-bash: pipenv: command not found
(venv) Aruns-MacBook-Pro:vidly arununnikrishnan$ sudo pipenv install django==3.0.8
sudo: pipenv: command not found
(venv) Aruns-MacBook-Pro:vidly arununnikrishnan$
```

Please help!

Comment: did you try with just `sudo pip install django`? the command is pip

Comment: @Arun Unnikrishnan always use a virtual environment for your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is

```
sudo pip install django==3.0.1
```

pipenv is not a valid command

Check the [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/install/) docs on installation.
It provides a step by step instruction, choose the OS required

and about the sudo

> The sudo command allows you to run programs with the security
> privileges of another user (by default, as the superuser). It prompts
> you for your personal password and confirms your request to execute a
> command by checking a file, called sudoers, which the system
> administrator configures.